# Ansible Conditional lookup

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook , and tasks in it looks like below. Both `push_config` and `import_consul` are not passed, so by default there are false.

```
  - name: checkout config-tibco repository
      git:
        repo: ssh://git@bitbucket.corp.contingo.com:7999/gwa/config-tibco.git
        dest: "/opt/awx/tmp/config-tibco/"
      when: "{{ push_config | default(false) | bool }} or {{ import_consul | default(false) | bool }}"
...
....
.....

 - name: Update Consul KV Store
   shell: curl --request PUT -d "{{item.split('=',1) [1]}}" "http://{{ consul_host }}:{{ consul_port }}/v1/kv//TEST/{{ bw_application_name.stdout }}/{{ app_profile }}/{{item.split('=',1) [0]}}"
   loop: "{{ lookup('file', '/opt/awx/tmp/config-tibco/properties/*.properties').splitlines() }}"
   when: "{{ import_consul | default(false) | bool }}"
```

I am expecting that second task - **update Consul KV Store** should be simply ignored, since the condition should be false. The lookup file that is expected in the **second** task will be only downloaded/checked out when the condition is made true (i.e. `import_consul`), so it gets checked out from GIT in the first task and made available for second task.

But I am getting below exception about Lookup file. Question here is, why is it even attempting to evaluating the task module when the condition is already set to false.

```
fatal: [host machine]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: could not locate file in lookup: /opt/awx/tmp/config-tibco/properties/*.properties"}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: Original message: could not locate file in lookup: /opt/awx/tmp/config-tibco/properties/*.properties

A: The `when` condition must be evaluated in each iteration because the condition might depend on the `item`. As a result, the `loop` must be evaluated before `when`.

---

Notes

- The [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/file.html#file-read-file-contents) plugin does not work with wildcards. Use [fileglob](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/fileglob.html#fileglob-list-files-matching-a-pattern) instead.
- To avoid errors, check the existence of the file(s) and terminate the play if the file(s) are not present.
- Always create at least empty file `default.properties`
- The `when` conditions (both first and second) will result in the warning

> [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{
>   import_consul|default(false)|bool }}

Fix it (the first one ditto)

```
when: import_consul|default(false)|bool
```